# How to read a cell of a sheet filled with floats containing German decimal point

Tags: python, python-3.x, openpyxl

I filled an Excel sheet with a correct float numbers based on the German decimal point format. So, the number 3.142 is correctly written 3,142, and if it is written 3.142 (or '3.142 by declaring it as a text entry in order to avoid English interpretation as 3142), then I want to report an error to the author of the Excel file.

So, I want to see a 3,142 in the first case when reading this file by openpyxl, and in the second case a 3.142 - just as writting by hand in Excel.

However, I see 3.142 in both cases. What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

The solution could be as follows:

```
sheets = []

workBook = openpyxl.load_workbook (filename = "sheet.xlsx")

for sheet in workBook:
    mySheet = []

    for row in sheet.rows:
        mySheet.append ([])
        myLine = mySheet [-1]

        for cell in row:
            if cell.value:
                if cell.data_type == 'n':
                    myLine.append (str (cell.value).replace ('.',  ','))

                else:
                    # if the input was erroneously 100000.22 instead of 100000,22, 
                    # the processing will come by here and keep the 100000.22 
                    # since it is no numeric data_type; later processing can then 
                    # detect that the input was/is not a German number
                    myLine.append (cell.value)

            elif cell.value == 0:
                # it seems strange to me that 0 is "no value" but I'm able to handle it
                myLine.append ("0")

            else:
                myLine.append ("")

    sheets.append (mySheet)
```

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to value of numbers openpyxl doesn't care about their formatting so it will report 3142 in both cases. I don't think coercing this to a string makes any sense at all.